# Working directory filesharing

Tags: java, rmi, working-directory

This is my first post. I just take a update to write what i did

```
import java.io.*;
import java.rmi.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class FileClient{
public static void main(String a[]) {

    Object[] choice = {"download", "upload"};
    int valg = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What do u want to do?", null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, "");
    switch(choice){
        case 0:
        try {
        String filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what do u want to copy? ");
        String name = "rmi://" + "localhost" + "/FileServer";
        FileInterface fi = (FileInterface) Naming.lookup(name);
        byte[] filedata = fi.downloadFile(ServerDirectory + filnavn);
        File file = new File(filnavn);
        BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file.getName()));
        output.write(filedata,0,filedata.length);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("FileServer exception: "+ e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
                    break;
                case 1:

                    break;
    }
}
}
```

The problem i have is that i cant choose the working directory in the code.

So what i learned was that u cant choose the Working Directory folder in java so i just put in paths so where i get the files and where i want to download them:

```
String PathToDownloadFolder = ("//C:/Hello/")
String PathToWhereIGetTheFile = ("//C:/server/")
byte[] filedata = cf.downloadFile(PathToWhereIGetTheFile + valgtFil);
BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream
                    (new FileOutputStream(PathToDownloadFolder + file.getName()));
```

Comment: I tried the  String ClientDirectory=("C://Users/Thomas/hei/");
         File file = new File(ClientDirectory, fileName); in FileImpl.java. Did not work

Comment: "Did not work" is not a good description of what happens. What do you want it to do, what does it do instead? If any exception, post the stack trace. Changing the working directory at runtime is impossible.

Comment: I want to choose where to download the file. I want a SERVER folder and a DOWNLOAD folder, so i can get file back and forth to those. the files i copy from my SERVER folder is saved in my project folder, and that i dont want. And by "Did not work" i mean that the file is saved in the project folder and not in the path folder i choose

Comment: `File targetFile = new File(DOWNLOAD_FOLDER, fileName);` You seem to have tried this, and it "did not work". How didn't it work? Show us the code you tried, because that's the appropriate way to do, so you must have missed something.

Comment: I have pasted a Edit with the code i used

Answer (score 0):

You construct an absolute path with

```
File file = new File(ClientDirectory + fileName);
```

But then you still use the file name when constructing the stream:

```
BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
```

Replace this line with

```
BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```

And it should be better.

That said, you should read the [Java IO tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/), because you don't use files and streams correctly. For example, you don't read all the bytes of your file, and you don't close streams in finally blocks.

Comment: I am going to read that tutorial, but it did not work. It still want to copy the file to the project folder.

Comment: The code you pasted is the code which **reads** the file. You must have a similar kind of error in the code that **writes** the file.

Comment: So, that means that either output is null, or filedata is null. If you want to be a serious developer, you'd better learn to debug your programs.

Comment: Its the FileClient.java thats read the file and FileImpl.java that downloads it. Because when i have String ClientDirectory=("C://Users/Thomas/hei/");
        File file = new File(ClientDirectory + filnavn); in my FileClient.java the file that I want to copy is done that in project folder

Comment: FileImpl, in the code you pasted, opens a file in the client directory and reads its content to a byte array. There is no downloading there. FileClient uses RMI to download a byte array from the server, and writes the bytes downloaded to a file (`filenavn`). I've not found in your code where this `filenavn` is declared.

Comment: String filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what do u want to copy? "); I write in the name of a file like hello.txt, then he find this file in ServerDirectory. Then he copy this file C://Users/Thomas/Dropbox/Prosjekt RMI/SERVER/hello.txt to the project folder.

Comment: Read your own code, for Christ sake: `File file = new File(filnavn);BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file.getName()));` The client thus writes the file to a file whose path is in the variable filenavn. I don't know what this variable contains, since it's not in the code you pasted.